# Dynamically duplicating div with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div called 'red' which displays messages sent by users on my webpage. The problem is that 'red' is only 40px long, and the messages usually go past the div. I'd like to add another duplicate of 'red' div on the webpage after a message is sent so the messages won't get out of the div boundaries.

```
<form action="action_page.php">  <!-- Message created here -->
<input type="text" name="userinput" value="message">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="red"></div> <!--- Messages shown here -->
```

**JS For Duplication**

```
var i = 0;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('red' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
   clone.id = "red" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    clone.onclick = duplicate; // event handlers are not cloned
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

So basically after a message is sent, a duplicated of 'red' is added for the next message. I'd like to avoid the 'resize' method or 'autoflow'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the JS you have now

Comment: Updated question, sorry.

Comment: you want to have a div to display a massage after the form submited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you're trying to do is extend the div for every message sent. Here's a perfect example for that http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/32/

```
var i = 1;
var p = 50;
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    p = p + 75;
    i++;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'draggable' + i);
    newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
    newdiv.style.top = +p + "px";
    newdiv.style.left = "20px";
    newdiv.style.border = '1px solid #000';
    newdiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
    newdiv.style.width = '75px';
    newdiv.style.height = '75px';
    newdiv.innerHTML = "draggable inner div";
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newdiv);

    var g = $('#draggable' + i);
    var o = $('#content');
    g.draggable({
        constraint: "#content",
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (g.position().top > o.height() - g.height()) {
                o.height(o.height() + 5);
                return true;
            }           
        },

        scroll: false
    });
    $("#content").height(o.height()+g.height());
});
```

What the code does is it adds an extra div called 'draggable' for the div 'content' which in your case would be the message.

Comment: Why on earth not use jQuery when you have it?

    `$('<div/>').prop('id', 'draggable' + i)
    .css({position:"absolute",top : +p + "px",....})
    .html("draggable inner div")
    .appendTo("#content");`

Comment: I don't know mplungjan, thank you for your solution.